# Object expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess Nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting this error haven't seen it before, have tried all the solutions to the similar questions here, I am trying to select a council where a tenant lives from a pre-populated council model, using through council history, the form shows up however when I press submit I keep getting this error. Appreciate any help with this problem.

```
Started PUT "/properties/6/build/council" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-18 22:32:55 +0100
Processing by Properties::BuildController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"wBWQaxtBioqzGLkhUrstqS+cFD/xvEutXnJ0jWNtSa0=", "property"=>   {"council_history"=>{"id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Save Property[council history]",  "property_id"=>"6", "id"=>"council"}
  Property Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" =   ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "6"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (  0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 62ms
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - CouncilHistory(#70308444526760) expected, got          ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70308443935640):
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:204:in `raise_on_type_mismatch'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb:8:in `replace'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:51:in `block in define_writers'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:94:in `block in assign_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:216:in `block in update_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.13)    lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:in `update_attributes'
  app/controllers/properties/build_controller.rb:23:in `update'
```

Property Model

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :address_attributes, :tenants_attributes, :meter_attributes,  :council_history, :council_history_attributes, :property_id, :council_id, :status
  belongs_to :user 

  has_one :council_history
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :council_history

  has_one :council, through: :council_history
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :council

end
```

Council Model

```
class Council < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :CouncilEmail, :name, :CouncilTel

  has_many   :council_history

  has_many   :properties, :through => :council_history 
end
```

Council History Model

```
 class CouncilHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :council_id, :property_id, :vacant 

  belongs_to :council

  belongs_to :property

 end
```

Select Council View Form

```
<h1>Select Council</h1>



<%= simple_form_for @property, :url => url_for(:action => 'update', :controller =>   'properties/build'), :method => 'put' do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :council_history do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.input :id, :collection => Council.all %>
  <%= builder.submit %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Build Property Controller

```
class Properties::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

   steps :tenant, :meter, :council, :confirmed 

  def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @tenants = @property.tenants.new(params[:tenant_id])
    @meter = @property.build_meter
    @council = @property.build_council_history
    render_wizard
  end

  def edit
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  end


  def update
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    params[:property][:status] = step.to_s
    params[:property][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @property.update_attributes(params[:property])
    render_wizard @property
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case it was strictly related with how i was naming my strong parameters.

`model_attributes` where `model` is your actual model name.
Just in case this is my code:

Parent controller strong params definition

`def well_params
        params.require(:well).permit(:name, :well_number, :api_number,
        :company_id, :permit_date, :spud_date,
        :inclination, :formation,
        :lateral_length, :lateral_depth, :measured_depth,
        stages_attributes: [:id, :stage_number, :stage_bottom, :start_date, :duration,
        :fluid, :proppant, :project_id, :created_at, :updated_at, 
        :stage_top,:well_id]
        )
    end`

Parent model def:

`class Well < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stages
...`

Child model def:

`class Stage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :well
...`

As you can see my fix was simply to rename what's right now having `stages_attributes`, before it was just `stages` and `well_stages` and you can not do this instead must be like it is on the snipet `stages_attributes`

Hope this helps!

PS: i found the solution in [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) where it describes how to code complex forms
if you take a look at the output of the form's action, basically tells you to use it as i'm describing

{
  'person' => {
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'addresses_attributes' => {
      '0' => {
        'kind' => 'Home',
        'street' => '221b Baker Street'
      },
      '1' => {
        'kind' => 'Office',
        'street' => '31 Spooner Street'
      }
    }
  }
}

It will tell you to use `addresses_attributes` again... `xxx_attributes`

Answer (score 1):

In your `Property` model you have `attr_accessible :council_history`, try removing it.

I didn't get to test this but I believe the problem is because you have `has_one :council_history`, the `simple_fields_for` is using this `:council_history` instead of generating `council_history_attributes` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, have done both of these, but now I am getting an error unknown attribute: council_history_attributes

Comment: Could you post your full trace in the question.  I want to see where that error comes from.

Comment: @cyclopse87, Oh you know what it's my bad, I meant to say `attr_accessible` instead of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the answer above.  Sorry about that, please try the updated answer.

Comment: When I removed the council_history the whole form is disappeared from the view.

Comment: Sorry my mistake that worked but when I try to submit the form nothing gets submitted here are the params  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wBWQaxtBioqzGLkhUrstqS+cFD/xvEutXnJ0jWNtSa0=", "property"=>{"council_history_attributes"=>{"council_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Create Council history", "property_id"=>"7", "id"=>"council"}

Comment: @cyclopse87, after having a look at your form code the only field you have there is council history id which is getting submitted.  So this looks correct.  What is it that you expected to submit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35801/discussion-between-cyclopse87-and-vinodadhikary)

Comment: Hi @vinodadhikary I almost sorted out for has_one association, are you able to chat later?